# Application resource path is different from development and IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

In my mvc application I set the resource like css and js like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="@Url.Content( "~/css/external/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" )"/> 
<!-- PLUGIN: jQuery UI styling -->
<link href="@Href( "~/Content/uploadify.css" )" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<!-- File uploader -->
```

in my `_Layout.cshtml`

It works in my development environment, it resolved to

```
/css/external/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
```

and

```
/Content/uploadify.css
```

Then I set up the application under IIS7 and set Alias as CommEditor

When I browse it all the resources are missing.

It is looking at

```
/CommEditor/css/external/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
```

and

```
/CommEditor/Content/uploadify.css
```

How should I set up the resource so that it works for both development and IIS7?

Answer (score 0):

For an alias, try setting the path of the app in IIS7.  Try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/460354/How-to-set-virtual-path-of-my-application-hosted-o

You should be able to use `~/folder/resource.ext` syntax in newer versions of mvc.  The ~ uses a relative path based on the location of the app.

Or, use `Url.Content("~/folder/resource.ext")` if that doesn't work, which should work in all versions.

Comment: I use @Url.Content("~/folder/resource.ext"), it doesn't work under IIS7